# If $f,g$ integrable then $f(x-y)g(y)$ integrable for almost every $x$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory

I am trying to prove that for two integrable functions $f,g: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ the function $y \mapsto f(x-y)g(y)$ is integrable for almost every $x$. By using the holder inequality I reduced this to showing that if a function is integrable then also its square is integrable but after browsing a bit I found [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/80016/product-of-two-lebesgue-integrable-functions-not-lebesgue-integrable) so I guess this leads nowhere. Any hints are welcomed.

Comment: This is called the convolution.  It is very important.  Try to derive some of the other properties found at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution

Comment: The function $x\mapsto\sqrt x$ on the interval $(0,1)$ is integrable but its square is not. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hint: consider $\int\int |f(x-y)g(y)| \, dy \, dx$, and use Tonelli's theorem to reverse the order of integration. If you can show this integral is finite, then $\int |f(x-y)g(y)| \, dy$ is finite for almost every $x$.

Comment: Tonelli says $$\int\int |f(x-y)g(y)| \, dy \, dx = \int\int |f(x-y)g(y)| \, dx \, dy.$$ The inside integral is plainly finite if $f$ is integrable and $g(y)$ is finite.  But how does that imply the outside integral is finite? ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Once you've switched the order of integration, $|g(y)|$ is just a constant in the inner integral, so you may bring it outside the (inner) integral (but still inside the outer integral)...

Comment: But you still have the factor $y\mapsto \int |f(x-y)|\,dx$, so the integrability of $g$ is not enough at that point. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: You also need to use the translation-invariance of the Lebesgue integral and the integrability of $f$.

Comment: aha!  I guess I was distracted by other aspects of the problem. ${}\qquad{}$