# The product of a bounded and an absolutely integrable function is absolutely integrable

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral, upper-lower-bounds

There is a theorem in Fourier Series where in the proof they have used the following result:
***`The product of a bounded and an absolutely integrable function is absolutely integrable`***
But the proof of this result has not been told to us. In this previously answered [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/56008/583398) , I have seen the proof but was not able to understand properly because of the terms *"almost everywhere"*. Actually, I'm merely a beginner in this topic of Integrability and Fourier Series. Can anyone provide me with a more elaborate form of this proof for a better understanding. I will be awfully greatful for this !
Thankyou.

Comment: The statement is false for Riemann integrability. It is obvious for Lebesgue integrability if the bounded function is also measurable.

Comment: Absolutely  integrable  functions are only Lebesgue integrable I guess ?